# Possível erro ortográfico no texto do link be-nice

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, localização

No link [be-nice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) o texto contêm uma palavra escrita

> indimidação.

Não conheço essa palavra, e pode ser que foi escrita errada, sendo que o correto seria

> intimidação

O que vocês acham? Existe uma forma de reportar o possível erro?

Comment: Sim, é um erro, de digitação. O lugar para reportar é aqui mesmo :) Somente os gerentes de comunidade podem editar esses textos de ajuda, vou avisá-los.

Comment: Então, aproveitando que o AP abriu este tópico, tem um errinho de digitação que já tinha notado antes mas deixei pra lá por ser pouca coisa:  "do mais experiente ao**s** mais iniciante"... btw, este é o melhor "termos de uso" que já vi, simplesmente sensacional.

Comment: @gustavox Esse erro tá onde?

Comment: no be nice...@Gabe

Comment: @gustavox Valeu!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os 2 erros (o @gustavox apontou outro nos comentários) foram consertados.

Aparentemente digitar n~ao é minha praia...

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Bem, só para ser chato, há mais dois errinhos que vi. O primeiro é que faltou o ponto final após o trecho "*melhor não escrever nada*" e o segundo é que há um problema na HTML da lista de itens dentro da seção "Não seja um idiota" - Nesta seção, o primeiro item (Ataques pessoais) está com o HTML como `<li>texto</li>`, enquanto que os outros itens estão com `<li><p>texto</p></li>`. A falta da etiqueta `<p>` no item de "Ataques pessoais" faz com que este item tenha espaçamento entre os parágrafos inconsistente com o resto do texto.

Comment: Você está correto. Precisa ser corrigido sim. Mas a importância é bem menor. Obrigado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Corrigido. O do HTML foi mais confuso, porque o original é em Markdown, mas acho que tá tudo certo agora. Obrigado!